# SUM SQL value to increment values per session

Tags: php, sql

This is very awkward, this is a very simple fetch value, equal to otherwise sum one and then save... but is not working...

I have a predefined value as 1010, so, I select the last entry in the SQL, if the last entry is grater than 1010 then get the value and add 1, then save it which now the last value would be 1011 correct? but is not....

```
$values_b = 1010;
$getval = 'SELECT number FROM table ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1';
$final = $con->query($getval);
$vals = $final ->fetch_array();
$numbers = $vals['number'];

if ($numbers > 1010){
$new_n = $numbers + 1;
$new_numbers = 'INSERT INTO table (number) VALUES ('$new_n')';
$con->query($new_numbers);
} else {
$new_numbers = 'INSERT INTO table (number) VALUES ('$values_b')';
$con->query($new_numbers);
}
```

Very simple, but the result some how is awkward, it doesn't save 1010 or 1011 or any of the sort... instead is saving 2325 and why is that???? I don't use this values anywhere else, those are unique variables but I really don't understand, this is the first time this is happening, my table is utf-8-general-ci and the column is INT(20) I have try VARCHART(100) but the result is almost the same...

What I'm trying to achieve is "simple", I have a per-defined number 1010, so, if this is the first record save that number 1010, if not, then get the last record say 1020 which mean that there are 10 records, just sum 1 to the last record 1020 + 1 = 1021 and save it... see, very simple, but for some reason is not doing it... so I was wondering if someone can help me solve this...

Thank you for taking the time

---

**SOLVED**
The problem here was the query, I was calling to a column with the incorrect name
this table has about 19 columns, the first 5 are
ID | Name | email | numbers ..... the column 16 is | number | 
I was calling number when in reality I should be calling for NUMBERS the result that I was getting was from another file, so, in other words, I was getting the result from B and adding 1 to B when I should be using A...
this is entirely my fault, I should paid more attention... sorry guys...

Comment: yes, it's, but that is not the problem, this is just a raw example of the whole code that I have, thanks for noticing...

Comment: ok, the per-difined number is 72402321, so on the first query, I check is the is a record and I print the array  [number] => 2014280136 which is weird because the I haven't save nothing just yet it should print 0's anyway, the value that is saving by adding 1 is 2014280137, so where does this number 2014280136 came from?

Comment: I tested your code and using a `WHERE` clause and as you have it, and it inserted `1101` (from 1100 - I inserted 1100 into my column as a start) into a column named `number`, so it's your query that's failing. I would also like to point out that you need to wrap your queries in double quotes, this `'INSERT INTO table (number) VALUES ('$new_n')';` will throw an error and should be `"INSERT INTO table (number) VALUES ('$new_n')";` --- Yet, if that is the way you have it for your own tests, then do show what you're actually using; it's deceiving.

Comment: You are correct about the double quotes, I should be using " instead of ' is just that my code the more I put in to the more complex it gets to the point where sometimes I forgot what variables I'm using... and I have it solved... the problem was yes the query but not exactly, the problem was the column that I calling....

Comment: Ah, cool. Glad to know you solved it. I had a feeling that's what it was. / Partially right ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$values_b = 1010;
$getval = 'SELECT max(number) as bignumber FROM table';
$final = $con->query($getval);
$vals = $final ->fetch_array();
$numbers = $vals['bignumber'];

if ($numbers > 1010){
$new_n = $numbers + 1;
$new_numbers = 'INSERT INTO table (number) VALUES ('$new_n')';
} else {
$new_numbers = 'INSERT INTO table (number) VALUES ('$values_b')';
}
$con->query($new_numbers);
```

Comment: nop, the big problem is that is not saving 1010 or if I add 1 to 1010 then it should save 1011 but is not, instead is saving 2325 and that is very...

Comment: It could be also because, the highest value in the table that is being retrieved because of the result is 2325